# Run JavaScript from address bar in a different IFrame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe, address-bar

Can I specify the IFrame in which the JavaScript code that I type in the address bar will run? Or is there any way at all to access an element that is not in the top frame from JavaScript code that I type in the address bar?

Since I am the local user of the computer, I assume that any code I myself type in the address bar is trusted to access all the IFrames. After all, I can just open the Console, which allows me to specify the IFrame, and type my code there, and I would get access to the element anyway. It's just more cumbersome.

Comment: nope, you can't. Otherwise it would be a way of bypassing the same origin policy because such an action can be caused by javascript. http://jsfiddle.net/yp87A/

Comment: Ok, but if the javascript is from another IFrame already, would it run from the top frame? Is the top frame always used for javascript typed in the address bar, even when typed from code, not by the human user?

Comment: it will run wherever it originated from. If the code in that fiddle was in an iframe, it would execute within that iframe.

Comment: Notice, when you focus the address bar, all of your selections inside of the iframe will go grey indicating that the iframe no longer has focus.

Comment: So where does code typed directly by the user in the address bar originate from? Does it have a specific iframe?